# Install Xdebug extension only for PHP7.1

Tags: 16.04, php, php7, xdebug

I have PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
When I'm trying to install Xdebug by using `apt-get install php-xdebug`, I'm getting `xdebug.ini` in directories 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1.

I don't need `/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and `/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` extensions, because I'm using only PHP 7.1 version.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What's exactly being asked here? Those extra ini files are harmless. If you don't need them, you can just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here (in my opinion):

1. Remove this extra-files of unnecessary version without any fear that this will effect on processes of workable version.
2. Compile php7.1 from source with xdebug extension (it's not so hard as it seems)